# How to show HTML5 validation messages on input change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have a form that I don't want to submit because I do an AJAX call instead, but I want the html5 validation messages displayed when an input is empty.

I manage to show the message when a button is clicked but what I really want is to show it on input change.

This works:

```
$('#link').click(function() {
    if (!$('#form')[0].checkValidity()) {
        $('#submit').click();
    }
});
```

But not this:

```
$('#input').change(function() {
    if (!$('#form')[0].checkValidity()) {
        $('#submit').click();
    }
});
```

See here for a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1anyLswt/2/

If you empty the field then click "test", the message is displayed: OK.

If you empty the field then press enter, the message is displayed: OK.

But if you empty the field then click elsewhere, the message is not displayed: KO.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: instead of $('#input').change use $('#input').blur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1anyLswt/4/)

```
$('#input').keyup(function() {
   if (!$('#form')[0].checkValidity()) {
       $('#submit').click();
   }
});
```

Comment: Pleasure @ThomasLulé !! Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Make use of jquery.validate

```
 <script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 <script src="js/additional-methods.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    // When the document is ready
    $(document).ready(function () 
    {

        $("#form").validate({
            rules:
            {
                name: "test",

                test: 
                {
                    required: true,
                    number: true
                }
            },
            messages: 
            {
                test: "Enter Number",

            },
        //perform an AJAX post to ajax.php
        });
        $("#form").submit(function(e)
        {
            var testval = $("#form");
            if( $("#ajaxform").valid())
            {
                    // Do Processing here
            }

        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: thank you but I have to display native html5 validation messages to be consistent with the rest of the application

Answer (score -1):

There is No such method(as far as i know)  that You can use it to check the field is empty or not, to do this you can use combination of Method or can use external plugins

the similar plugin is Jquery validation

after putting reference to it and adding following to your script

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
 debug: true,
 success: "valid"
});
var form = $( "#myform" );
form.validate();
$( "button" ).click(function() {
alert( "Valid: " + form.valid() );
});
```

the above code validates the entire controls in your form .
please refer to this link

[Jquery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/)